# Not able to get string value from SharedPreferences in Flutter build widget

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and I need a `userName` string value which I have in my `SharedPreferences` but it returns `Future<String>` rather than a string

```
class PickupLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget scaffold;
  final CallMethods callMethods = CallMethods();

  PickupLayout({
    @required this.scaffold,
  });

  getPref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String auth = prefs.getString("USERNAMEKEY");
    return auth;
  }

  Future<String> _fetchAllData() async {
    return HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 //   final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    Constants.myName = await HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference();
    return (HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference() != null)
        ? StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: callMethods.callStream(userName: getPref()),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.data != null) {
                Call call = Call.fromMap(snapshot.data.data);
                print("stream builder working!!!!!");
                if (!call.hasDialled) {
                  return PickupScreen(call: call);
                }
              }
              return scaffold;
            },
          )
        : Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

I need to pass username in `callMethods.callStream(userName: "userName")`

```
HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference()
```

is simply a method to return Future String

```
static Future<String> getUserNameSharedPreference() async{
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return await preferences.getString(sharedPreferenceUserNameKey);
```

Comment: can you try removing await in `preferences.getString()` statement in getUserNameSharedPreference() and make it static String ?

Comment: it shows the error:
 A value of type 'Future<SharedPreferences>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SharedPreferences'.

Shared prefrences returns Future<String> and we cannot receive it in String or Static String.

Comment: According to your error ‘SharedPreferences.getInstance();’ returns a ‘Future<SharedPreferences>‘ type and you cannot simply assign it to a type of ‘SharedPreferences’ as you do.

Comment: Also, whenever you call the ‘getPref()’ method you need to put ‘await’ before, because it’s an asynchronous function. So you need to do it as the following ‘ stream: callMethods.callStream(userName: await getPref())’